# PowerShell PSModulePath's missing in VSCode

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

$env:PSModulePath is incorrect in VSCode.

I updated HKCU:\Environment\PSModulePath to include directories for locally developed modules.  When I start PowerShell via Windows 11 Terminal, the directories are included in the PSModulePath environment variable.  When I launch the PowerShell terminal in VSCode, they are not. The only PowerShell extension I have installed is the one from Microsoft. I am using PowerShell 7.3.4 in both consoles.

How do I fix this?

Thank you

Edit:
When I run VSCode as administrator, $env:PSModulePath does include the paths listed in HKCU:\Environment\PSModulePath; when I start normally, it does not.  It seems that @jdweng is correct.

In both cases, it loads the same number of extensions.  And
`Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKCU:\Environment -Name PSModulePath`
returns the same values.

Nevertheless, I believe that @mklement0 is also right in saying that something in the startup is interfering with the environment though I can't figure out what.

Comment: If you've updated the persistent definition of environment variable `PSModulePath` via the registry, any subsequently launched processes (that aren't launched from processes that themselves were launched before that update) should see the updated definition. If that isn't the case, the implication is that something in the process in question performs a process-level modification of the environment variable in question.

Comment: You are probably running with a different account.  I suspect you are an admin and inside PS you are not an admin.  Try running by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Thank you.  I believe you're both have the right idea.  I've edited the question after more testing prompted by your comments.

Comment: @bob, are you using the _same_ user account to run non-elevated vs. elevated? If so, your symptom remains a mystery: a given account should see the same environment variables and should use the same profile files, whether running in an elevated process or not. A simple way to rule out incidental problems: If you reboot, does the symptom persist?

Comment: I hate to admit it but a reboot resolved the issue on my home machine.  My office computer had an interesting quirk.  The behavior persisted following a reboot.  Then I noticed that the user settings contained an entry for terminal.integrated.env.windows.  It was empty but present.  When I removed it and restarted VSCode, PSModulePath had the expected values.  I tried to recreate the problem by restoring the user setting but cannot make the behavior return.  Even new values in the reg key get picked up as expected.  Thanks for the help!